# Are there any good editors for asp.net on smartphones?

Tags: ide, asp.net, mobile

I came across [coderun](http://www.coderun.com/) the other day does anyone know any better editors/ide's espeially that can be used relatively easily on some of todays smartphones for asp.net ?

Answer (score 5):

Some more background might be helpful so we can understand your needs. My immediate response is that smartphones are great at content consumption but suck for content generation. This is particularly true when you're talking about such syntactically picky activities as programming.

Answer (score 0):

There won't an IDE that would be productive to use on this generation of smart phones. The amount of input required to program is impractical on such a small device, especially considering that the input device is the display.

Especially, considering that the highest voted answer to [this question on best investment for programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36007/which-are-the-best-investments-you-have-done-for-your-career-as-programmer/36018#36018) is "Dual Monitors and a decent keyboard."

Use the time you spend programming on a smart phone to read specs/articles or switch your brain off to prevent burn out.